# cant create encrypted usb drive on raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, luks, disk-encryption

I have a raspberry pi 4. I have followed the instructions at
https://linuxconfig.org/usb-stick-encryption-using-linux

I have created and recreated the partitions, tried fat32, apt, and gpt. I started out departing from the instructions by using gparted gui to create two primary partitions on a USB drive, but have since reproduced exactly the steps given. The directions don't seem to work if you have a fully partitioned drive so I removed all partitions. I did that just now with gparted, and the second partition (the encrypted one) I needed to close encryption before it would allow me to delete. So starting with a blank USB drive with no partitions.

```
sudo  fdisk -l
```

clearly shows my drive is /dev/sda

```
Disk /dev/sda: 115.52 GiB, 124037038080 bytes, 242259840 sectors
Disk model: USB DISK 3.0    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7DFCBD4A-32FA-427F-B298-8CA9229DB3FF
```

then I type

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

the resutls are

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (34-242259806, default 2048): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-242259806, default 242259806): +64GB

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 59.6 GiB.
Partition #1 contains a ext4 signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: y

The signature will be removed by a write command.

Command (m for help): n
Partition number (2-128, default 2): 
First sector (125001728-242259806, default 125001728): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (125001728-242259806, default 242259806): 

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 55.9 GiB.
Partition #2 contains a crypto_LUKS signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: y

The signature will be removed by a write command.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

I am surprised that the signatures were still there after removing all partitions. I selected to remove the pre-existing signatures. The next step seems to be formatting the drives in fat

```
sudo mkfs.fat /dev/sda1
sudo mkfs.fat /dev/sda2
```

resulting in

```
$ sudo mkfs.fat /dev/sda1
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
$ sudo mkfs.fat /dev/sda2
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
```

skipping step 5 filling the drive with random content. The next step is to encrypt the second partition.

```
sudo cryptsetup -h sha256 -c aes-xts-plain -s 256 luksFormat /dev/sda2
```

which is successful. Next we mount the partition with

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 private
```

which is successful. The instructions suggest my encrypted partition is now available as /dev/mapper/private, but the only thing there looks like a mapping to ../dm-0, I did cat the private link and got many screens of binary content before killing the output.

```
/dev/mapper $ ls -ltr
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Dec 24 17:54 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Dec 24 18:52 private -> ../dm-0
```

This next part is where everything goes wrong. the /mnt/private folder exists because of the many previous attempts, but to be thorough I just deleted it and re-created it with

```
sudo rm -rf /mnt/private
sudo mkdir /mnt/private
sudo mount /dev/mapper/private /mnt/private
```

which once again results in

```
mount: /mnt/private: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/private, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I have been as thorough as I can, but this simply does not work for me and I now need your help please.

Answer (score 2):

> /dev/mapper/private, but the only thing there looks like a mapping to ../dm-0

Yes, this is correct, `/dev/mapper/private` is just a nice "human readable" symlink for the device, internally device mapper devices are always `/dev/dm-<number>`, you should use the `/dev/mapper/private` symlink it will be always available.

> mount: /mnt/private: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/private, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

The problem is you created the FAT filesystem first and then used `cryptsetup` to setup the LUKS encryption which overwrote the FAT filesystem signature with LUKS signature so you ended up with encrypted device that is not formatted. You need to create the FAT filesystem after LUKS:

1. Create LUKS: `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda2`
2. Open the device: `cryptsetup open /dev/sda2 private`
3. Format the cleartext device to FAT: `mkfs.fat /dev/mapper/private`
4. Now you can mount it: `mount /dev/mapper/private /mnt/private`